# MasterDetailPage: Accepting something other than a Page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am following the tutorial here on [Master-Detail Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page)

One question I am having:

Part of the solution calls for an item class as follows:

```c#
public class MasterPageItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string IconSource { get; set; }
    public Type TargetType { get; set; }
}
```

And in the Xaml file, you call it as this:

```XAML
   <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:MasterPageItem}">
            <local:MasterPageItem Title="Radio" IconSource="hamburger.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:RadioPage}" />

            <local:MasterPageItem Title="Item 1" TargetType="{x:Type temp:ContactsPage}" />
            <local:MasterPageItem Title="Item 2" TargetType="{x:Type temp:TodoListPage}" />
            <local:MasterPageItem Title="Item 3" TargetType="{x:Type temp:ReminderPage}" />
            <local:MasterPageItem Title="File 4"  TargetType="{}Foodaddy" />
        </x:Array>
    </ListView.ItemsSource>
```

What I want to do is for "File 4", rather than creating a view, I would rather send in a string, (or better an Enum), so I can call different functions. Example: Open a webpage, log out, etc. How do I modify TargetType?

Comment: you would need to modify MasterPageItem to support this new behavior

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[If you notice in this piece of code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page#creating-and-displaying-the-detail-page) you will see that the `OnItemSelected` method is handling the event and expecting for a `MasterPageItem`:

```c#
void OnItemSelected (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
    if (item != null) {
        Detail = new NavigationPage ((Page)Activator.CreateInstance (item.TargetType));
        masterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
        IsPresented = false;
    }
}
```

It is doing the navigation directly through the event handler (it's not the `MVVM` way to do that).

I guess [@Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason)'s [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570803/masterdetailpage-accepting-something-other-than-a-page#comment88151364_50570803) fits for you. Here's a way to achieve that:

You can create your own model to replace the `MasterPageItem` and handle its properties in a `MasterDetailMenuViewModel`, for example, and modify the handling to something more accurate for your need.

See the example below:

#### Create an amazing model to your menu items

```c#
public class AmazingMenuItem
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ItemIconSource { get; set; }
    public EnumAction ActionType { get; set; }
    public object ActionParameter { get; set; }
}

public enum EnumAction
{
    OpenPage = 0,
    ShowMessage = 1,
    PopToRoot = 2
    /* ... and so on  */
}
```

#### Handle it in the view model*

```c#
public class MenuViewModel : SomeINotifyPropertyChangedImplementation
{
    public Command ItemSelectedCommand { get; }
    /*
        Other properties
    */

    public MenuViewModel()
    {
        ItemSelectedCommand = new Command<AmazingMenuItem>(ExecuteItemSelected);
    }

    private void ExecuteItemSelected(AmazingMenuItem item)
    {
        if(item != null)
        {
            switch(item.ActionType)
            {
                case EnumAction.OpenPage:
                    var detail = (App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail;

                    if(detail is NavigationPage)
                        detail.PushAsync((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.ActionParameter.GetType()));
                    else
                        (App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.ActionParameter.GetType()));

                    break;
                case EnumAction.ShowMessage:
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(item.ActionParameter.ToString(), "Ok", "Cancel");

                    break;
                case EnumAction.PopToRoot:
                    (App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage)?.Detail.PopToRootAsync();

                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>* - Supposing you have made the bindings correctly</sup>

It's not a complete implementation, but I hope you've figured out a general idea of it.

Let me know if I can help you to get thru this <sub>(and sorry for any English mistake, it's not a native here)</sub>.